# Module not found when deploying on Vercel

Tags: javascript, github, next.js, vercel

I've created a website in NextJS. It runs fine via npm run dev and such but when building and deploying it in Vercel, I'm getting the error that it can't find the module, but it can find it just fine in npm run dev in VS Code. npm run build also works fine in VS Code. What is the issue here?

[This is the github repository it is using](https://github.com/Maxterino/MaxPortfolioNextJS)

[Full Vercel log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Lpn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake when importing the Navbar in `/app/page.js`. The path to Navbar should be `@components/Common/Navbar` (notice the uppercase `Common`).